# I am using the "mediation" package in R, and I can't figure out why the upper confidence intervals are cut off. How do I increase the digits?

Tags: r

I am using the "mediation" package in R, and the upper confidence intervals only result to the hundredth place (often this is 0.00). The lower confidence intervals do not have this problem. I am attaching my code and the output as well with the problem circled in red. I would so appreciate help! I have already tried changing "boot = TRUE" to "boot = "norm", "basic", "perc", and "bca". These did not work.

```
# Load data and fit models (same as before)

    dataframe <- read.csv("dataframe.csv")
    model1 <- lm(outcome ~ treat + covariate1 + covariate2, data = dataframe)
    model2 <- lm(mediator ~ treat + covariate1 + covariate2, data = dataframe)
    model3 <- lm(outcome ~ treat + mediator + covariate1 + covariate2, data = dataframe)

# Perform mediation analysis

    results <- mediate(model2, model3, treat = "treat", mediator = "mediator", outcome =     "outcome", covariates = c("covariate1", "covariate2"), boot = TRUE, sims = 1000)

# Display summary

    summary(results)
```

I tried changing Boot = "" to different things, but none of them worked

Comment: It's hard to help if we can't run your code since you haven't shared the data. Can you make your example reproducible by adding a sample of data with `dput()`? You're more likely to find an answer.